# Openlitespeed server + WordPress: can't upload large files

Tags: php, wordpress, openlitespeed

I realize that this has been asked before, but the previous questions seem to be nginx based servers. I am running into this issue using Openlitespeed on a digitalocean droplet. Specifically, when I upload files over ~200MB this is the error:
Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page

I am running Wordfence, and have tried putting the firewall into learning mode as well as disabling it, and still cannot upload anything larger than about 200MB even though I have enabled unlimited file upload sizes.

Reading through the nginx solution, I see that this was the given fix:
client_max_body_size 10M;

Is there an equivalent in openlitespeed?

Any help would be greatly apprecaited!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using OpenLiteSpped with cyberpanel? If so, you can change the upload limit on the control panel

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you hit the PHP limit, you should expect a warning on the WordPress page.

```
XXfilename exceeds the maximum upload size for this site.
```

**Fix method**

Edit the **/usr/local/lsws/lsphp81/etc/php/8.1/litespeed/php.ini** file to configure PHP parameters.

To increase the allowed file size, for example, you would make the following edits:

```
upload_max_filesize = 500M
post_max_size = 500M
```

Then restart php with the command `killall -9 lsphp` to make settings take effect

Note 1: If you are using a different version, please adjust the number in the URL accordingly.

Note 2: If you hit the PHP timeout limit, please increase the value of **max_input_time** from the php.ini file as well.

If the above method does not help, then you might need to check both the server and PHP error logs.